# Fluent Wait and WebDriver Wait - Differences

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have seen both `FluentWait` and `WebDriverWait` in code using Selenium. `FluentWait` uses a Polling Technique i.e. it will be poll every fixed interval for a particular `WebElement`. I want to know what Does `WebDriverWait` do with `ExpectedConditions`?

Consider following Java example:

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 18);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Account")));

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Account"));
element.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL);
element.click();
```

Does `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Account"))` monitor for `linkText("Account")` to be clickable or does it wait 18 seconds before clicking?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your example `wait.until(ExpectedConditions...)` will keep looking (every 0.5s) for `linkText` 'Account' for 18 seconds before timing out.

[`WebDriverWait`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) is a subclass of [`FluentWait<WebDriver>`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html).
 In `FluentWait` you have more options to configure, along with maximum wait time, like polling interval, exceptions to ignore etc. Also, in your code, you don't need to wait and then `findElement` in the next step, you could do:

```java
WebElement element = wait.until(
        ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Account")));
```