# Selenium webdriver - keep user logged in (java)

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to do a simple Selenium test using webdriver (firefox).

```
Steps:
1. Open login page 
2. Log in
3. Open subpage
```

My problem is that when a subpage is loaded user is no longer logged in. Thanks in advance for tips how to solve this.

```
public class Test  {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("https://example.com/login");

    WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.id("login_username"));
    WebElement pass = driver.findElement(By.id("login_password"));
    WebElement loginButton = driver.findElement(By.id("auth-login-submit"));

    login.sendKeys("login");
    pass.sendKeys("pass");
    loginButton.click();

    driver.get("https://example.com/subpage");
  }
}
```

Comment: it *may* be calling `driver.get()` too fast.. maybe you should wait until it says `You are now logged in as X`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped. I use Thread.sleep(5000) in try/catch. Is there a better way?

Comment: Better way is add expected condition instead of `Thread.sleep()` and wait until text `You are now logged in as X` is displayed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19908296/fluent-wait-and-webdriver-wait-differences

Answer (score 1):

> Thanks a lot, it helped. I use Thread.sleep(5000) in try/catch. Is
>   there a better way? –  aponski Mar 28 at 9:00

Implicit waits as the best choice

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

> An implicit wait is to tell WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain
>   amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are
>   not immediately available. The default setting is 0. Once set, the
>   implicit wait is set for the life of the WebDriver object instance.

This is just one-time configuration

Source: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp